# SSRS Group values outside the group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Below is my tablar matrix. with multiple groups.

[image]

the result after executing is as follows.

[image]

In the highlighted red text box in image (OrganizationId2), I want to see a values as

```
=OrganizationId /OrganizationId1
```

when I am trying to copy the expression from OrganizationId and paste it does not allow me as aggregate value is out of the group. I tried ReportItems expression, since i have many recurring rows, this did not work.
Can any one help me in achieving this.?

Comment: Have you tried using a lookup? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Add the scope to your expression. Like this:

```
=(Fields!YourField.Value,  "OrganizationId") / (Fields!YourField.Value, "OrganizationId2")
```